# Is there an Emacs-specific solution to printing Emails?

Tags: email, notmuch, pretty-print

I'm using notmuch for reading and writing emails. This works fine, but sometimes I still do need to print emails. Here the available tools don't shine. Out of the box, using `#`, printing results in an ugly monospaced text. It's OK, but aren't there better solutions?

Looking for what is available in the Linux universe, I found tools like `enscript`, `muttprint` or `a2ps`. They all seem to be rather old and unflexible (e.g. with UTF8). So I thought that since I am reading the mails in Emacs anyways, there might be an Emacs-specific solution (and if it just tunes`ps-print` so that the result looks nice).

What I am looking for:

- Fancy display of the header infos
- Non-monospaced font (even if the original mail is not HTML)
- Nested coloring of nested levels of quotations
- Ideally, convert and print the HTML part if present

Does something like that exist, Emacs-specific or not? Any comments or ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is https://github.com/aclements/notmuch/blob/master/emacs/notmuch-print.el though I'm not sure how useable it is.

Would be nice to print the whole thread too.

Comment: This is a link-only answer, so it should be deleted. If you present an answer with such a link, the answer should at least summarize the info found at the link that answers the question.

Comment: The link points to the built-in notmuch print feature, which uses `muttprint` or `ps-print`. I remember that muttprint was basically not usable for me, though I do not remember why. Ps-print just prints the buffer. I actually use this feature, but it's very primitive.